# How to derive the kalman gain with the form of K=Pxz/Pz?

Tags: kalman-filter

please see the formula and reference in the page https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/10-Unscented-Kalman-Filter.ipynb

Traditional formula of gain is expressed like the form in the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

But how to derive the form as K=Pxz/Pz?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Qiqin Zhan.  Can you please edit your question and write out the formulas you are having difficulty with?  Please include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve/understand the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving/understanding it. Please also take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Comment: On *Robotics* we are fortunate enough to have MathJax support enabled, allowing you to easily create subscripts, superscripts, fractions, square roots, greek letters and more. This allows you to add both inline and block element mathematical expressions in *robotics* questions and answers. For a quick tutorial, take a look at [How can I format mathematical expressions here, using MathJax?](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/130/37)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.